# How can I reuse the Activity code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, code-reuse

We can use `<include />` to include a layout into another.

I'm including **activity_main.xml** into **activity_second.xml** using `<include />`.

**activity_main.xml** has a `<TextView />` and a `<Button />`.
And the `<Button />` has a handler `doThis(View v){..}` in **MainActivity.java**

How do I reuse the Button Handler in the **SecondActivity.java**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Fragments for that

Answer (score 2):

There's no button handler thing. It is `OnClickListener`. And to reuse it either copy that source to second activity class or create `MyActivity` class which your `MainActivity` and `SecondAcivity` would extend and put common code there.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similair to your question. Don't think it's better than using Fragments but in a nutshell.

You have your layout_main.xml. You can import other XML (menu.xml) into that like this:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/layoutMenu"
    layout="@layout/menu" />
```

Create a Menu.java Class like this (I copied this from my own class so it is not complete but for the idea of it):

```
 public class Menu {

ImageView buttonNieuws;

public void set(Activity activity, String currentPage) {

    // Button NIEUWS
    buttonNieuws = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.button_nieuws);

    if (!currentPage.equals("nieuws")) {

        buttonNieuws.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                        Nieuws.class);
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    } else {

        buttonNieuws.setImageDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.button_nieuws_on));
    } ...
```

And then in your main Activity Class you can use code like this to link it all together:

```
 Menu menu = new Menu();
 menu.set(this, currentPage);
```

Huge drawback is that unlimited Activities get stacked on top of each other. This is my temporary solution because i didn't get into Fragments yet.